# Yii CDbCriteria AND OR

Tags: php, yii

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();


        $criteria->addCondition('admin_status = ' . Transaction::ADMIN_STATUS_WAITING);
        $criteria->addCondition('status = ' . Transaction::ORDER_STATUS_WAITING);
        $criteria->addCondition(
            'DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL ' . $this->period . ' DAY) > DATE(order_date)'
        );
        if($this->type != null) {
            $criteria->addCondition('type = ' . (int)$this->type);
        }
        $criteria->addCondition('admin_status = ' . Transaction::ADMIN_STATUS_REJECTED . ' AND  status != ' . Transaction::ORDER_STATUS_REJECTED, 'OR');
```

What i now have:

*(((admin_status = 0) AND (status = 0)) AND (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 120 DAY) > DATE(order_date))) OR (admin_status = 2 AND  status != 2)*

what I need have:

***(***(((admin_status = 0) AND (status = 0)) AND (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 120 DAY) > DATE(order_date)))**)** OR (admin_status = 2 AND  status != 2)

How to join 3 first criterias to one ?

I need to have `(criteria1 AND criteria2 AND criteria3 ) OR (CRITERIA 4)`

Comment: The outcome of the code is the same as the required output. Perhaps you can add a better scenario where this is useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, just do it all inside one condition.  and even tho they're class constants, I still suggest using parameter binding.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('((((admin_status = :admin_status_waiting) AND (status = :order_status_waiting)) AND (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL :period DAY) > DATE(order_date)))) OR (admin_status = :admin_status_rejected AND status != :order_status_rejected)');
$criteria->params = array(
    ':period' => $this->period,
    ':admin_status_waiting' => Transaction::ADMIN_STATUS_WAITING,
    ':order_status_waiting' => Transaction::ORDER_STATUS_WAITING,
    ':admin_status_rejected' => Transaction::ADMIN_STATUS_REJECTED,
    ':order_status_rejected' => Transaction::ORDER_STATUS_REJECTED
);
```

Comment: This is what I use if I am not pragmatically deciding which conditions to include.

Answer (score 1):

I think its already what you want if you have checked properly

```
(
           (
           (admin_status = 0) AND (status = 0)
           ) AND (DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 120 DAY) > DATE(order_date))
) OR (admin_status = 2 AND status != 2)
```

**You are doing nothing but want to add one pair of extra parenthesis.**